# Why can't I get the same results as GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

`GridSearchCV` only returns a score for each parametrization and I would like to see an Roc Curve as well to better understand the results.  In order to do this, I would like to take the best performing model from `GridSearchCV` and reproduce these same results but cache the probabilities.  Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from tqdm import tqdm

import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

data = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=20, n_classes=2, 
                           random_state=1, class_sep=0.1)
X, y = data


small_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('rfs', SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100))), 
    ('clf', LogisticRegression())
])

params = {
    'clf__class_weight': ['balanced'],
    'clf__penalty'     : ['l1', 'l2'],
    'clf__C'           : [0.1, 0.5, 1.0],
    'rfs__max_features': [3, 5, 10]
}
key_feats = ['mean_train_score', 'mean_test_score', 'param_clf__C', 
             'param_clf__penalty', 'param_rfs__max_features']

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0)

all_results = list()
for _ in tqdm(range(25)):
    gs = GridSearchCV(small_pipe, param_grid=params, scoring='roc_auc', cv=skf, n_jobs=-1);
    gs.fit(X, y);
    results = pd.DataFrame(gs.cv_results_)[key_feats]
    all_results.append(results)


param_group = ['param_clf__C', 'param_clf__penalty', 'param_rfs__max_features']
all_results_df = pd.concat(all_results)
all_results_df.groupby(param_group).agg(['mean', 'std']
                    ).sort_values(('mean_test_score', 'mean'), ascending=False).head(20)
```

Here is my attempt at reproducing the results

```
small_pipe_w_params = Pipeline([
    ('rfs', SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100), max_features=3)), 
    ('clf', LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced', penalty='l2', C=0.1))
])
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0)
all_scores = list()
for _ in range(25):
    scores = list()
    for train, test in skf.split(X, y):
        small_pipe_w_params.fit(X[train, :], y[train])
        probas = small_pipe_w_params.predict_proba(X[test, :])[:, 1]
        # cache probas here to build an Roc w/ conf interval later
        scores.append(roc_auc_score(y[test], probas))
    all_scores.extend(scores)

print('mean: {:<1.3f}, std: {:<1.3f}'.format(np.mean(all_scores), np.std(all_scores)))
```

I'm running the above multiple times as the results seem unstable.  I have created a challenging dataset as my own dataset is equally as hard to learn.  The groupby is meant to take all iterations of `GridSearchCV` and average & std the train and test scores to stabilize results.  I then pick out the best performing model (C=0.1, penalty=l2 and max_features=3 in my most recent model) and try to reproduce these same results when I put those params in deliberately.

The `GridSearchCV` model yields a 0.63 mean and 0.042 std roc score whereas my own implementation gets 0.59 mean and std 0.131 roc.  The grid search scores are considerably better.  If I run this experiment out for 100 iterations for both GSCV and my own, the results are similar.

Why are these results not the same? They both internally use `StratifiedKFold()` when an integer for cv is supplied... and maybe `GridSearchCV` weights the scores by size of fold? I'm not sure on that, it would make sense though.  Is my implementation flawed?

edit: `random_state` added to SKFold

Comment: Try specifying `random_state`.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with random_states, can I just use `np.random.seed(1)`? Random state is set in the `make_classification` call.  Using the numpy seed, I still get about a 0.5 difference between GSCV and my own method.

Comment: I mean here: `StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0)`.

Comment: added, still 0.05 difference

Comment: I increased the n_splits to 10 and the top GSCV scores are about 0.71 now whereas my hand implemented ones are still at 0.58 roc.

Comment: What about adding random_state to the Random Forest?

Answer (score 2):

If you set the set the random_state of the `RandomForestClassifier`, the variation between different `girdsearchCV` would be eliminated.

For simplification, I have set n_estimators =10 and got the following result

```
                                                             mean_train_score           mean_test_score
param_clf__C    param_clf__penalty  param_ rfs_max_features       mean        std     mean          std         
        1.0      l2                   5 0.766701    0.000000    0.580727    0.0  10 0.768849    0.000000    0.577737    0.0
```

Now, if see the performance on each split (by removing `key_feats` filtering) of the best hyper parameters, using

```
all_results_df.sort_values(('mean_test_score'), ascending=False).head(1).T
```

we will get

```
    16
mean_fit_time   0.228381
mean_score_time 0.113187
mean_test_score 0.580727
mean_train_score    0.766701
param_clf__C    1
param_clf__class_weight balanced
param_clf__penalty  l2
param_rfs__max_features 5
params  {'clf__class_weight': 'balanced', 'clf__penalt...
rank_test_score 1
split0_test_score   0.427273
split0_train_score  0.807051
split1_test_score   0.47
split1_train_score  0.791745
split2_test_score   0.54
split2_train_score  0.789243
split3_test_score   0.78
split3_train_score  0.769856
split4_test_score   0.7
split4_train_score  0.67561
std_fit_time    0.00586908
std_score_time  0.00152781
std_test_score  0.13555
std_train_score 0.0470554
```

let us reproduce this!

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0)
all_scores = list()

scores = []
weights = []


for train, test in skf.split(X, y):
    small_pipe_w_params = Pipeline([
                ('rfs', SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, 
                                                               random_state=0),max_features=5)), 
                ('clf', LogisticRegression(class_weight='balanced', penalty='l2', C=1.0,random_state=0))
            ])
    small_pipe_w_params.fit(X[train, :], y[train])
    probas = small_pipe_w_params.predict_proba(X[test, :])
    # cache probas here to build an Roc w/ conf interval later
    scores.append(roc_auc_score(y[test], probas[:,1]))
    weights.append(len(test))

print(scores)
print('mean: {:<1.6f}, std: {:<1.3f}'.format(np.average(scores, axis=0, weights=weights), np.std(scores)))
```

> [0.42727272727272736, 0.47, 0.54, 0.78, 0.7]
>   mean: 0.580727, std: 0.135

Note: `mean_test_score` is not just simple average, its a weighted mean. 
Reason being `iid` param

From [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV):

> **iid :** boolean, default=’warn’ If True, return the average score across
>   folds, weighted by the number of samples in each test set. In this
>   case, the data is assumed to be identically distributed across the
>   folds, and the loss minimized is the total loss per sample, and not
>   the mean loss across the folds. If False, return the average score
>   across folds. Default is True, but will change to False in version
>   0.21, to correspond to the standard definition of cross-validation.
>
> Changed in version 0.20: Parameter iid will change from True to False
>   by default in version 0.22, and will be removed in 0.24.