# Should GridSearchCV score results be equal to score of cross_validate using same input?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I am playing around with scikit-learn a bit and wanted to reproduce the cross-validation scores for one specific hyper-parameter combination of a carried out grid search.

For the grid search, I used the `GridSearchCV` class and to reproduce the result for one specific hyper-parameter combination I used the `cross_validate` function with the exact same split and classifier settings.

My problem is that I do not get the expected score results, which to my understanding should be exactly the same as the same computations are carried out to obtain the scores in both methods.

I made sure to exclude any randomness sources from my script by fixing the used splits on the training data.

In the following code snippet, an example of the stated problem is given.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate, StratifiedKFold, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import NuSVC

np.random.seed(2018)

# generate random training features
X = np.random.random((100, 10))

# class labels
y = np.random.randint(2, size=100)

clf = NuSVC(nu=0.4, gamma='auto')

# Compute score for one parameter combination
grid = GridSearchCV(clf,
                    cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=2018),
                    param_grid={'nu': [0.4]},
                    scoring=['f1_macro'],
                    refit=False)

grid.fit(X, y)
print(grid.cv_results_['mean_test_f1_macro'][0])

# Recompute score for exact same input
result = cross_validate(clf,
                        X,
                        y,
                        cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=2018),
                        scoring=['f1_macro'])

print(result['test_f1_macro'].mean())
```

Executing the given snippet results in the output:

```
0.38414468864468865
0.3848840048840049
```

I would have expected these scores to be exactly the same, as they are computed on the same split, using the same training data with the same classifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `mean_test_f1_macro` is not a simple average of all combination of folds, it is a weight average, with weights being the size of the test fold. To know more about the actual implementation of refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55720287/6347629) answer.

Now, to replicate the `GridSearchCV` result, try this!

```py
print('grid search cv result',grid.cv_results_['mean_test_f1_macro'][0])

# grid search cv result 0.38414468864468865

print('simple mean: ', result['test_f1_macro'].mean())

# simple mean:  0.3848840048840049

weights= [len(test) for (_, test) in StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, random_state=2018).split(X,y)]
print('weighted mean: {}'.format(np.average(result['test_f1_macro'], axis=0, weights=weights)))

# weighted mean: 0.38414468864468865
```